# Hub Distance - 'Layer not found'

Tags: qgis, error, mmqgis

I am trying to calculate the distance between a polyline (River) and multiple points. However after installing the MMQGIS plugin and running a Hub Distance between the two layers the error comes up 'Hub layer River not found'

Answer (score 1):

Without checking the plugin source code, I would expect that the hub layer has to be a point layer. You could try to extract all river nodes and use those as hubs.